# Change ImageUrl of image outside Repeater with value from inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, repeater, imageurl

I have a Repeater with several items. With the use of a timer, the items are highlighted one after another with this code:

```
((HtmlControl)Repeater1.Controls[nextHighlight].Controls[1]).Attributes["class"] += "highlighted";
```

One of the values that the items hold is an ImageUrl (collected from a database), which is to be used with an asp:Image outside the Repeater.

How can i get the value - hopefully from the Timer_Tick function - in the Repeater item, so that i can change the ImageUrl? It doesn't matter how i should store the ImageUrl in the Repeater (Hiddenfield, maybe?) - whatever is the easiest to get from the Timer_Tick function.

Comment: How do you think that a server-side timer will be able to update client-side HTML? You'll have to do this on the client side.

Comment: Because the Timer_Tick causes a postback. It does set the class of the repeater-item to "highligted" server-side.

Comment: No, it doesn't. How can an event on the server cause the client to post?

Comment: Well it does work.. I use updatepanels, and everytime the timer ticks, i can use backend code to modify the frontend.

Comment: Sorry, no. There's something that you're leaving out. You may not even know about it. There may be a client poll or something; maybe even a timer on the client. But absent something like SignalR, there is nothing that the server can do to _initiate_ a connection to the client. There are technologies in which the client _maintains_ a connection to the server, and may even issue a long-timeout request, hoping the server will respond. But I guarantee you it's initiated by the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get RepeaterItem of child repeater in Timer_Tick event using NamingContainer method.

```
 HtmlImage aImage=(HtmlImage)RptRow.Parent.Parent.Parent.FindControl("aImage"); 
 // RptRow is RepeaterItem 
 aImage.Src = "Your url";
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I changed it to Image (asp:Image), but it works. Thank you very much!